# radio button not clickable

Tags: android

I have made an application with `four` radio buttons.The problem is that the last radio button is unclickable initially untill you click some other button.After clicking some other radio button,the last radio button becomes clickable.plz tell me how to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

```
private void uncheckAllOptions()
    {
        myOption1.setChecked(true);
        myOption2.setChecked(true);
        myOption3.setChecked(true);
        myOption4.setChecked(true);

        myOption1.setChecked(false);
        myOption2.setChecked(false);
        myOption3.setChecked(false);
        myOption4.setChecked(false);

}
```

I am using this code to save the state of the radio buttons but the last radio button always remains unclickable untill and unless one of the radio button among the first 3 is clicked

Comment: can't help without code. Add the code.

Comment: posted the code please help now

Answer (score 5):

> Use `clearCheck() function of RadioButtonGroup to clear all
>   RadioButtons`.

Using `myOption4.setChecked(false);` can't checked next time until you check another RadioButton.

**Like,**    `radioButtonGroup.clearCheck();`

- [See This From Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#clearCheck%28%29)

Comment: @user1522540 ,its working for me are you use `radioButtonGroup?`,see link in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

First of all put prop clickable=false in RadioButton-4 in XMl:

then suppose you want to make if clickable RadioButton-4 after clicking the FIRST RadioButton, then set RB-4 clickable=True in listener.

See following:

```
rb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                    rb4.setClickable(true);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What exactly, you want to do? Tell me with some details.

Comment: Thank you sir the problem is solved thanks a lot for your help

Comment: How did you do that?? You also increase my knowledge, by telling me.